# Find the value of return variable based on the value of n?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

```
function fun(n) {
  let i,
    j,
    p,
    q = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    p = 0;
    for (j = n; j > 1; j = j / 2) {
      ++p;
    }
    for (k = 1; k < p; k = k * 2) {
      ++q;
    }
  }
  return q;
}

let val_q = fun(36);
console.log(val_q);
```

My confusion:

1. Outer loop runs $n$ times.
2. The loop with $j$ will run this many times:

Assume $n=32$
Then $j=32,16,8,4,2,1$

Let us generalize.

```
For p=1, j=32
For p=2, j=16
For p=3, j=8
For p=4, j=4
For p=5, j=2
For p=6, j=1
```

I assume from my basic mathematics,
$p=n\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^{p-1}$

I can't solve this to find the $O(p)$ in terms of $n$.

3. For the loop with $k$, here's what my thought process is:

Doing similar stuffs, we get

```
For q=1, k=1
For q=2, k=2
For q=3,k=8
```

And so on.
We can generalize that:

$k=2^q$

We also have:

$k<p$
That means if we put all the values of k and p, we get:
$q=\log_2(n)+1-p$

BUT
Finally:
We can write: Value of $q=n\cdot \log_2(n)+1-p$

This is the best I can do. :D

Comment: P is about log n, q is about log p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The outer loop runs $n$ times.
2. The first inner loop (the loop in $j$) runs approximately $\log_2 n$ times. This is because it runs until, by dividing $n$ by $2$, we obtain a number $\leq 1$. This means that it runs $m$ times, where $m$ is the smallest integer such that: $\frac{n}{2^m}\leq 1$. This happens when $n \leq 2^m$, i.e. $m \geq \log_2 n$ (the logarithm is a monotonic increasing function, so we can "apply it to inequalities"). More precisely, since we require $m$ to be integer, $m$ will be $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$, i.e. the integer superior part of $\log_2 n$.
   Actually, if we want to be more precise, the first inner loop works with an integer index $j$, but each time we divide by $2$ this is not guaranteed (unless $n$ is a power of $2$). This means that from cycle to cycle we can have several roundings. For instance, if $n=15$, the values of $j$ will be
   $15, 7, 3, 1$, so the loop will run $3$ times instead of $4$. This leads us to a number of runs of $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$ (i.e. the integer part of $\log_2 n$).
   Thus $p$ will be $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$.
3. The second inner loop (that in $k$) do the same thing as the loop in $j$, but it starts from $1$ and goes up (so we don't have the rounding problems and we use the integer superior part $\lceil \cdot \rceil$). The calculations are the same and we get an increment in $q$ of $\lceil \log_2 p \rceil$ at each iteration of the outer loop.

Summing up, for $n$ runs of the outer loop, we get:
$$q=n\cdot\left(\bigl\lceil \log_2 \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor \bigr\rceil\right) \ .$$

Note that $p$ is reset at each iteration of the outer loop while $q$ is not.

The asymptotic time complexity is thus: $O(n\log n))$ because the most expensive operation inside the outer loop is the loop in $j$ which runs $O(\log n)$ times, while the loop in $k$ is a lower-order term.